# Timers in a console program

Tags: c++, winapi

I am writing C++ code using the Windows API.

If I want to use `SetTimer` and its friends inside a program that does not present a GUI, I know that I can use `SetTimer(NULL, 1, 2000, Timerflow)`, with `NULL` being the `hWnd` argument.

How do I write the code for handling, starting and killing the timer?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [`CreateWaitableTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492.aspx), [`SetWaitableTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289.aspx) and [`WaitForSingleObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687032.aspx). No callbacks or message handling needed.  See [MSDN's example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687008.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906.aspx) function directly using the Win32 API, and without the use of any wrapper classes (MFC, etc.).

Keep in mind that that windows timers work with the GUI event loop.  If you don't process events using the [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936.aspx) or [`PeekMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644943.aspx) functions, you won't get notified when the timer elapses.  You'll also need to create a window to which the timer will be attached (the [`WM_TIMER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902.aspx) message will be reported in that window's [window procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633569.aspx).

Check out the documentation for [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936.aspx) to learn how to write an event loop.  Also take a look at the "[Creating a Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644901.aspx#creating_timer)" to learn how to handle the [`WM_TIMER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902.aspx) message.

#### Edit: Overview of steps to take

1. **Write a window procedure**: See below for an example.
2. **Register a window class**: define the window class and set the window procedure to the above function.  Use the [`RegisterClass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to register the structure.
3. **Create a window**: Use the [`CreateWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to create a window of the class you just registered.
4. **Run the event loop**: Use the [`GetMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644936.aspx) function to process messages.  The [`DispatchMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call in that loop will forward `WM_TIMER` events to your window procedure and you can handle the message from there.

Steps 1, 2, and 3 should be part of your [`WinMain()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.  Here is an overview of the key steps (intentionally incomplete, check documentation to know how to handle errors and cleanup):

```
LRESULT __stdcall MyWindowProcedure
  ( HWND window, UINT message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam )
{
  if (message == WM_TIMER) {
    // timer elapsed.
  }
  return DefWindowProc(window, message, wparam, lparam);
}

int __stdcall WinMain ( HINSTANCE application, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int )
{
    ::WNDCLASS klass;
    // ...
    klass.lpfnWndProc = &MyWindowProcedure;
    RegisterClass(&klass);
    // ...
    HWND window = CreateWindow(klass.lpszClassName, ...);
    // ...
    const DWORD SECOND = 1000;
    const DWORD MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
    UINT_PTR timer = SetTimer(window, 0, 2*MINUTE, 0);
    // ...
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, window, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
       TranslateMessage(&message);
       DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Comment: is there a example for this settimer with callback func codes? because i read the "Creating a Timer"  but still don't understand how to code the main structure of the handler and where to place the getmessage() thingy.

Comment: @Wee: you'll have to dig deeper to find a complete window registration + window procedure + timer creation example based on only the Win32 API.  Unfortunately most of that code has nothing to do with the timer.  I'll provide a small edit to show the key steps.

Comment: i'm kind of confused now...or is there alternatives type of timer that is easier to implement for my case? thanks!

Comment: Your question was about using the Win32 API's `SetTimer()` function without "classes".  AFAIK, the posted instructions are the way to use `SetTimer()` using the raw Win32 API.  Alternatives for Windows will likely wrap all this for you.  "Portable" alternatives will likely just schedule callbacks and `sleep()` until the next callback is ready to fire or wrap this code and use whatever is available on other systems.

Comment: @Wee: Have a look at `CreateWaitableTimer()` (and related functions) and `WaitForSingleObject()`.  No callbacks or message handling needed.

Comment: @Wee Tiong, you're asking for a timer that does an asynchronous callback into your program. This is dangerous because there's no guarantee that your program is in a safe place to be interrupted. Therefore Windows does not provide such a timer; it relies on your polling the message queue to identify a safe time to do the callback.

Comment: @Remy, you should make that an answer.

Comment: Thanks alot André Caron  & Mark Ransom, i will try to make it work for my project!! thanks again!!!